# 'Debug' does not contain a definition for 'Print'

Tags: c#, console

In the following code I would like to just output "hi" into a console window as a test when both of the check boxes are checked.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        show.Text = inputText.Text;
        if (check1_cont && check2_cont == true )
        {
            Debug.Print("hi");
        }
    }
```

The only problem is that in System.Diagnostics, the 'Print' in 'Debug.Print' doesn't seem to exist. I've checked https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.print(v=vs.110).aspx and the Print method does exist. Any help regarding a solution to an absent Paint method would be much appreciated.

EDIT 1:

Apparently Debug.WriteLine doesn't give an error, but when I run the program and check the two boxes and press the button, no console appears.

EDIT 2:

In case it helps anyone, here is the full code for the GUI application that I am using.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace normieap
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public Boolean check1_cont = false;
        public Boolean check2_cont = false;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            show.Text = inputText.Text;
            if (check1_cont && check2_cont == true )
            {
                MessageBox.Show("hi");
            }

        }
        private void check1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            check1_cont = true;
        }
        private void check2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            check2_cont = true;
        }

    }
}
```

The button is going to cause multiple things to go at once, one of the things I would like to go at once is an instance of a console window of some sort to open.

EDIT 3:

This is meant to be a application for PC but for some reason when I started the project, Visual Studio 2015 community thought it was an application for a phone and is causing problems with PC exclusive commands. If someone could give information on how to fix that as well, that would be great.

Comment: I guess you are either looking for `Debug.WriteLine(..)` or `Console.WriteLine(...)`

Comment: Do you have a class called `Debug` in your project. What if you do `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("hi");`, does that work? Or perhaps are you building for a windows phone or some similar platform and not using the full .NET framework?

Comment: For Edit 3, honestly you are likely just better off just creating a new project then copying your files over.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to not be using the full desktop framework and instead are using some kind of mobile framework. For example, if you check [Silverlight's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug_methods(v=vs.95).aspx) you can see `Debug.Print` is not available.

If you check the "Version information" for Print you will see

> **Version Information**
>   **.NET Framework**
>   Available since 2.0

Switch to `Debug.WriteLine("hi")` instead, that should work in all frameworks, its version information says

> **Version Information**
>   **Universal Windows Platform**
>   Available since 4.5
>   **.NET Framework**
>   Available since 1.1
>   **Portable Class Library**
>   Supported in: portable .NET platforms
>   **Silverlight**
>   Available since 2.0
>   **Windows Phone Silverlight**
>   Available since 7.0
>   **Windows Phone**
>   Available since 8.1

If you are not seeing output I would recommend showing what your test variables are instead.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    show.Text = inputText.Text;
    Debug.WriteLine(check1_cont.ToString());
    Debug.WriteLine(check2_cont.ToString());
}
```